# Desktop application publishing to FTP in VS Express 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to publish a desktop application to a FTP location for updating over the web. Conceptually this works fine, I've published to my local disk, manually copied the files up there, installed from that location, and updates are automatically installed.

Ideally though I'd like to not have to publish to local and copy, I'd like to publish straight to FTP or even WebDAV. When entering an FTP location though I get this error:

```
Failed to connect to 'ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx/' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx'.
The components for communicating with FrontPage Server Extensions are not installed.
```

Google tells me that on previous Visual Studio versio I could add the "Visual Studio Web Authoring Component" through Add/Remove programs and repair, but that doesn't exist in VS 2012. I'm using VS Express 2012 for Windows Desktop.

How do I install the required components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Installing Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web gives you the right components:**

**Article**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537667.aspx

**Download**: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx?templang=de-de

*Sidenotes:*

*The FrontPage Server Extension is available as Apache Mod, and IIS extension.*

*IIS:* http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/frontpage-server-extensions/installing-the-frontpage-server-extensions-on-iis#02

*Apache:* http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache/Apache/ModFrontPage